# PyInstaller Error when converting Python 3.6 code to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I made a script with Python 3.6 and I´m trying to convert it to an .exe. I already install everything I need, but Im showing a weird error. Im using python-docx, but it does not say anything about it in [the official supported packages documentation](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages). I just want to know whats wrong and how to fix it. This is the error.

Sorry if it is a bit long. The script consist of a main file and several others, is to long to post here and also Im using threading.

> C:\Users\barrerakj\Desktop\Jarvis>pyinstaller.exe busqueda.py 180
>   INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1 180 INFO: Python: 3.6.1 181 INFO: Platform:
>   Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1 182 INFO: wrote
>   C:\Users\barrerakj\Desktop\Jarvis\busqueda.spec 185 INFO: UPX is not
>   available. 189 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
>   ['C:\Users\barrerakj\Desktop\Jarvis', 
>   'C:\Users\barrerakj\Desktop\Jarvis'] 189 INFO: checking Analysis
>   189 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
>   190 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph... 195 INFO:
>   Initializing module graph hooks... 199 INFO: Analyzing
>   base_library.zip ... Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pyi
>   nstaller-script.py", line 11, in 
>       load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()   File
>   "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller__main__.py", line 90,
>   in run
>       run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller__main__.py", line 46,
>   in run_bui ld
>       PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
>   line 788 , in main
>       build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build' ))   File
>   "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
>   line 734 , in build
>       exec(text, spec_namespace)   File "", line 16, in    File
>   "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
>   line 212 , in **init**
>       self.**postinit**()   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py",
>   line 161 , in **postinit**
>       self.assemble()   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
>   line 317 , in assemble
>       excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py",
>   line 560, in  initialize_modgraph
>       graph.import_hook(m)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 1509, in import_hook
>       source_package, target_module_partname, level)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 1661, in _find_head_package
>       target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)   File
>   "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py",
>   line 209, in  _safe_import_module
>       module_basename, module_name, parent_package)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 2077, in _safe_import_module
>       module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 2115, in _load_module
>       m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 2951, in _load_package
>       self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 2167, in _load_module
>       self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 2585, in _scan_code
>       module, module_code_object, is_scanning_imports=False)   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 2831, in _scan_bytecode
>       global_attr_name = get_operation_arg_name()   File "C:\Users\barrerakj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages\pyinstaller-3.2.1-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
>   line 2731, in get_operation_arg_name
>       return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index] IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2286 Python 3.6 is not supported yet.

Comment: O.M.G! Well, thanks for the link @Jarad. Very helpful. Guess I´ll downgrade.